# Using CSS3 transitions on "top" positioning

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I understand it is possible to use CSS3 animations on "top" positioning.

I have a graphic that I wish to transition by sliding it up just 50px when the user scrolls past a certain point.

I have managed to get the text to change but I haven't been able to get it to smoothly move from 50px to 0px, instead it "jumps" sharply.

Here is a JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/0rkbz7ox/

It works by removing the class "hidden" which adjusted the `top` value back to `0` from `50` but it does not animate, despite adding `transition` to the original classname.

The CSS for the graphics:

```
.about-graphic{-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;}
.about-graphic.hidden{position:relative;top:50px;}
```

Comment: what kind of question is that, that you give an answer to your question with a delay of 20 seconds???

Comment: @simon I realised my mistake quickly after posting the question. I figured I might as well post the answer in case anyone else comes along and needs this answer rather than deleting the question. (I answered 2 minutes after I posted the question, not 20 seconds, don't exaggerate)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `position: relative; top: 0;` to `.about-graphic` like this:

```
.about-graphic {
  ... // Your transitions
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
```

You can increase the duration of transition to see the effect clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered my mistake.

The original state requires `top:0;` and `position:relative` in order to animate, all the original CSS must be there.

```
.about-graphic{top:0;position:relative;-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;}

.about-graphic.hidden{top:50px;}
```